# Why does lichess ban players?

Tags: lichess

Few days ago I was watching a game review on lichess and found out one of the player's account was banned. Any idea why lichess does that?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Chess SE! Could you please provide more information on the game and the players? A link to both the game and lichess' policy would be very useful in this context.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, lichess rarely *bans* players. What they usually do is flag their profile (usually for using chess computer assistance), remove their rating, and prevent them from p laying in tournaments and/or rating games. This is not a full ban.

To answer your question:

Lichess flags players for a variety of reasons, but (as mentioned above) they usually flag players for using chess computer assistance. They may also be flagged for sandbagging - artificially increasing or decreasing their rating.

If you want to know why are particular player was flagged, check their profile. There should be a large red banner informing you what has happened.

If you are wondering how the process of reporting/flagging players works, that would be a separate question.

Answer (score 6):

The two main reasons:

- Lichess detected that the player was very likely cheating.
- The player used profanity or broke some rule of conduct.

Comment: Profanity is a fairly rare reason for banning.